# Ne pas lire (raconter) une / d' histoire

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu une histoire à mes enfants.
>
> Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu d'histoire à mes enfants.
>
> Ce soir, je n'ai pas raconté une histoire à mes enfants.
>
> Ce soir, je n'ai pas raconté d'histoire à mes enfants.

D'après vous, quelle variante est meilleure ? Je pense que les deux options, "une" et "de" sont possibles. Est-ce correct ?

Comment: D'une manière générale, raconter d'histoire (des histoires) singnifie mentir.

Comment: Je dirais la deuxième ou la dernière. Il est vrai que 'raconter des histoires' peut signifier autre chose mais dans ce cas je ne crois pas qu'il y ait de confusion possible.

Comment: On peut raconter une histoire inventée sans que ce soit un mensonge. Et sans texte.

Comment: Oui, la preuve: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpLpQmBxrlc ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I**

Il n'y a pas à proprement parler une variante, ni une forme qui soit meilleure que l'autre mais il y a deux formes qui correspondent à des sens différents. Cependant, c'est une question difficile et « de » peut correspondre soit à l'article indéfini soit à l'article partitif (de la, de l, de, d') ; c'est la nature du nom qui suit qui determine cela et il est dans certains cas très difficile de voir la différence entre  « des »  indéfini et « des » partitif (voir « LBU ed. 14  § 583 b) »).
Les explications sont faites sur la base de deux références dont l'une traite l'article partitif en tant qu'article défini (Kalmbach, grammaire  du français pour le finnophone, et LBU¹) mais pour un traitement selon la terminology standard (cependant pas en profondeur) voir  « LBU ed. 14 § 584 c) » ; il n'y a pas de différence dans la logique d'application, le nouveau point de vue prouvant seulement que la nature des deux ne fait qu'une, excepté pour un détail.
Il n'est pas possible de commencer à dominer cette question du choix de l'article sans de longues explications, et j'ai peu rechigné à inclure toute l'information que je considère du point de vue de mes besoins personnels nécessaire pour une bonne compréhension du sujet.

*Examples montrant le même principe pour l'article partitif*

- Il a pris **de la** tarte. → Il n'a pas pris **de** tarte.
- Il a lu **du** Flaubert. →  Il n'a pas lu **de** Flaubert.
- Il a mangé de l'élan. → Il n'a pas mangé **d**'élan.

**II**

[grammaire pour l'étudiant finnophone (Jean-Michel Kalmbach)](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html)

> **Variation des formes de l’article indéfini** [L'article partitif n'existe pas selon la théorie de cette grammaire et c'est un article indéfini massique.]
>
> Les formes de base de l’article indéfini sont « *un* », « *une* », « *des* », « *du* »,   « *de la* » (et la variante devant voyelle « *de l’* »). Dans certains cas, on utilise une autre forme :
>
> - quand l’article indéfini détermine un nom au pluriel précédé d’un adjectif antéposé, il prend habituellement (dans le code écrit) la forme « de » ;
> - quand l’article indéfini détermine un groupe nominal qui est complément direct d’un verbe à la forme négative, il prend souvent la forme « de », mais ce n’est pas systématique ;
> - après la préposition de, les formes d’article commençant par un d (des, du, de la, de) ne sont pas exprimées, elles « s’effacent ». C’est la règle d’effacement.

On passe au développement du second item, comme c'est celui qui couvre la question de la présente page FSE.

> *Modifications dans une phrase négative* (voir  « LBU ed. 14 § 584 c) 1° » pour le traitement selon la terminology standard)
>
> Forme « *de* » devant CVD et sujet postposé
>
> Quand l’article indéfini (toutes les formes, c’est-à-dire singulier, pluriel et massif) détermine un groupe nominal qui est complément de verbe direct (CVD) d’un verbe à la forme négative, il prend généralement la forme « de » :
>
> ♦ J’ai une voiture. vs Je n’ai pas encore de voiture.
> ♦ J’ai remarqué des fautes. vs Je n’ai pas remarqué de fautes.
> ♦ Nous n’avons pas appris de mots nouveaux.
> ♦ Aujourd’hui, je n’ai pas eu besoin de prendre de médicaments.
> ♦ Ne fais pas de bruit.
>
> L’arti­cle indéfini prend éga­le­ment la for­me « de » quand il dé­ter­mi­ne un GN sujet postposé d’un ver­be à la for­me négative d’une cons­truc­tion impersonnelle avec le pronom con­ju­ga­teur « il » (le sujet occupe la même position qu’un complément de ver­be direct) :
>
> ♦ Il faut un autre collaborateur. → Il ne faut pas d’autre collaborateur.
> ♦ Il reste encore du fromage ? → Il ne reste plus de fromage.
> ♦ Il se produisait parfois des accidents. → Il ne se produisait jamais d’accidents.

D'après ce qui vient d'être expliqué, donc,

- « Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu/raconté **d**'histoire(**s**) à mes enfants. »

correspond a la forme affirmative, normalement écrite comme suit.

- Ce soir, j'ai  lu/raconté **une/des** histoire(**s**) à mes enfants.

C'est la forme la plus courante ; dans cette forme la négation est dite être « *absolue* ».

[Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11349.php)

> DE ou D' + NOM dans les phrases négatives
> Devant un nom d'objet direct ou sujet « réel » dans les phrases négatives, on emploie « *de* » ou « **d'** » servant d'article partitif ou indéfini si la négation est absolue (Kalmbach, « totale »). [Dans le cas contraire elle est appelée *relative* ou (terminology de Kalmbach) *partielle*.]
> Qu'est-ce que la négation absolue ?
> Si le nom peut être précédé de « aucun » ou de « aucune quantité de », c'est une négation absolue :
> ♦ Laurent ne fait pas de faute. (Il n'en fait aucune)
> ♦ Il n'y a pas de cours de chinois sur le site.
> ♦ N'avez-vous donc plus d'espoir ?

*On a donc un test de base pour décider si une négation est absolue : sommairement exprimé, ce test est que si on peut dire « aucun(e) » c'est une négation absolue (et donc « *de* » est la forme de l'article).*

**III**

C'est à la   § 584 c)   de  LBU 14ième édition (**Lorsqu'on transforme une forme affirmative en forme négative.**), au « 2° »  que l'on va trouver une analyse qui justifie l'utilisation de la forme habituelle de l'article dans les phrases négatives, où il est, dans la terminology de Kalmbach « un déterminant de CVD/sujet postposé » et dans celle de Grevisse et Gousse « un article indéfini ou partitif accompagnant un objet direct ou un sujet logique (ou réel) ».
On y distingue trois cas :

> - 1/ La phrase (ou le membre de phrase) a un sens positif
> - 2/ Si la négation ne porte pas réellement sur le nom
> - 3/ Si le syntagme nié s'**oppose** à un autre syntagme de même fonction

*Exemples relevant du « 1/ »*

> ♦ On ne fait pas d'omelette sans casser DES œufs (prov. dans Ac. 2004, s. v. omelette). [= On casse nécessairement des œufs.] [(user LPH) Apparemment mal placé, devrait se trouver sous le paragraphe « § 584 c) 3° » (*Avec **sans***), justifié par « verbe négatif dans principale », mais avec *sans* le verbe négatif résulte en un sens positif, d'où la possibilité de ce classement puisque « œufs » est COD de « casser ».]
> ♦ N'avez-vous pas DES amis pour vous défendre ? [= Vos amis devraient vous défendre.]
> ♦ Est ce que vous pouvez empêcher qu'on ne donne DES sérénades à votre femme ?  — Le *ne* est explétif (cf.
> § 1023)  (MUSSET, Capr. de Mar., 1,2.)
> ♦ L'anomalie même de l'histoire empêche qu'elle [= l'héroïne du récit] n'y attache **DE L**'importance
> (BEAUVOIR, Deux, sexe, t. II, p. 49).

*Exemples relevant du « 2/ »*

> ♦ On n'y voyait presque jamais DES barques de pêche (P. BENOIT, Axelle, p. 10). [= On y
> voyait éventuellement des barques, mais non des barques de pêche.]
> ♦ Je n'ai pas amassé DES millions pour envoyer mon unique héritier se
> faire casser la tête en Afrique I (AUGIER, Effrontés, I, 2.) [= J'ai amassé
> des millions, mais non pour...]

*Exemples relevant du « 3/ »*

> ♦ Elle n'a pas demandé Du vin, mais de la bière.
> ♦ Nous ne disons pas DU mal de lui ! - L'**opposition** est implicite; (IONESCO, Amédée,
> p. 256.)
> ♦ (user LPH) Il ne décrit pas un incident mais un déroulement sans problèmes.

*Réserves*

> Si *un* est le numéral, il se maintient dans la construction négative :
> ♦ Je n'ai plus UN euro ; comp. Je n'ai plus D'euros (ordinairement au plur.) [
> — Pourtant *de* est bien plus fréquent que *un* dans le tour *Il ne se passait pas DE jour que* [= sans que, cf. § 1013, c] des demandes d'affectation
> [...] ne parvinssent au capitaine (GRACQ, Rivage des Syrtes, p. 127).
> D'une manière générale, *un* semble se maintenir plus facilement que
> *du* ou *des* :
> ♦ Si elle ne trouve pas UN prêtre pour s'occuper d'elle exclusivement (STENDHAL, L. Leuwen, LIX).
> ♦ Les comédiennes ne courent pas UN pareil danger (E. et J. DE GONC., Ch. Demailly, LV).
> ♦ Je ne vous fais pas UN reproche des néologismes (ib., XXVIII).
> *Un* s'impose dans certains cas :
> Cet esprit de calcul qui n'abandonne point
> UN vieux commerçant (BALZAC, Envers de l'hist. cont., Pl., p. 151).
> ♦ Jamais aucune femme n'a aimé UN eunuque (FLAUB., Corresp., cit. Rob., s. v. ombilical). 30
> ♦ Le maréchal soutenait que l'amour ne constituait pas UN sentiment particulier (E. DE GONC., Chérie, LXXIX).

*Conclusion pour le type de phrase en question (Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu une histoire à mes enfants.)*

« 1/ » et « 2/ » ne sont pas applicables mais « 3/ » l'est et donc si « une » est utilisé l'interlocuteur ou le lecteur comprendra que la personne a bien lu quelque chose à ses enfants mais ce n'était pas une histoire comme à l'accoutumée. Avec « une » on peut rendre cela explicite et renseigner l'interlocuteur ou le lecteur entièrement en ajoutant en faisant participer au discours ce référent qui est représenté par un syntagme du même type (c'est à dire dans le cas présent, quelque chose qui peut être lu).

- Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu une histoire à mes enfants, mais de l'histoire de France.
- Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu une histoire à mes enfants, au lieu de cela j'ai choisi deux petit poèmes.

Il est utile de se rappeler que cet usage est un problème pour l'utilisateur du français.

> ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-11349.php)

[…] on emploie du, de la, de l', des, si la négation n'est pas absolue mais, dans ce cas, il faut considérer la nuance de style ou de sens, pour comprendre si on est face à une négation absolue ou une négation relative ce qui n'est pas toujours aisé.
Je ne crois pas qu'il ait fait d'erreurs. (je pense qu'il n'en a jamais fait)
Je ne crois pas qu'il ait fait des erreurs. (à ma connaissance, il n'a pas fait d'erreurs)

**IV** **Considérations supplémentaires**

Le « 2/ » ci-dessus, tel que développé dans LBU mérite une attention plus grande, que l'on trouve dans la grammaire finnophone (Kalmbach).

> **La néga­tion porte sur un autre élé­ment que le CVD** (caractères gras dus à user LPH)
>
> La néga­tion peut aussi être partielle en ce sens qu’elle ne porte pas sur le com­plé­ment direct, mais sur un autre élé­ment de la phrase, par ex­em­ple sur **l’ad­jec­tif** qui caractérise le complément (et non pas sur tout le com­plé­ment) :
>
> ♦ Il ne faut pas y accorder une *grande* importance. [On peut y accorder de l’importance, mais pas trop.]
> ♦ Il n’a pas obtenu des résultats *vraiment intéressants* [Il a bien obtenu des résultats, mais qui ne sont pas intéressants.]
> ♦ La police n’a pas trouvé des preuves *décisives* contre le suspect. [La police a donc trouvé des preuves, mais elles n’étaient pas décisives.]
>
> C’est éga­le­ment le cas quand la néga­tion porte sur un **ad­ver­be** ou un **complément  de phrase de temps**, com­me souvent, tou­jours, ou **de manière** etc. Ces élé­ments sont in­di­qués en italiques dans les ex­em­ples suivants :
>
> ♦ *Demain* nous n’irons pas faire **du** ski.
> ♦ Avec le temps qu’il a fait cet hiver, on n’a pas *souvent* fait **du** patinage sur le lac.
> ♦ Autrefois, les gens ne mangeaient pas **de la** viande *tous* les jours.
> ♦ Cette année, on n’est pas allés acheter **du** vin *chez le producteur*. [mais ailleurs]
> ♦ Les chercheurs n’ont pas obtenu **des** résultats *im­mé­dia­te­ment*.
> ♦ Adecco ne pourra pas vous proposer **des** missions *avant* votre arrivée en France.
> ♦ Vous ne pourrez pas fabriquer **du** fromage avec *des moyens aussi dérisoires*.
> ♦ La sépara­tion des déchets de verre est im­por­tan­te car on ne peut pas produire **du** verre incolore *à partir d’un verre coloré*.
> ♦ Les fran­çais ne boivent *plus aussi souvent* **du** vin aux repas qu’il y a encore vingt ans.
>
> Autre ex­em­ple de ce type : dans la première des deux phrases suivantes, l’arti­cle « des » est devenu « de » (né­ga­­tion totale), mais dans la deuxième, il ne change pas. En effet, la deuxième phrase signifie « Il m’arrive d’ou­blier des choses, mais pas un visage ». Le lo­cu­teur oublie donc certaines choses, mais pas tout (né­ga­­tion partielle) :
>
> ♦ Je n’ai pas oublié de noms ?
> ♦ Je n’oublie jamais un visage. [(user LPH) Ce type d'exception à la règle résulte de situations sous-tendues par un contexte de possibilités contraires réelles, soit généralement connu soit que l'on comprend comme étant sous-entendu par le locuteur.]
> ♦ Il ne mord jamais un passant. (*Mais il mord ; sous entendu par le locuteur, c'est un chien qui mord.*)
> ♦ La foudre ne détruit jamais un paratonnerre. (*généralement connu*)]

Il y a également trois autres topiques d'intérêt que le lecteur voudra peut être consulter dans la référence citée ci-dessus (**Ne… que**, **Ni… ni**, **Affirmation cachée en négation**)

¹ <sub>Un téléchargement de la 14ième édition du livre « *Le Bon Usage* » peut être fait à partir du lien suivant :

https://www.pdfdrive.com/le-bon-usage-grammaire-fran%C3%A7aise-14e-%C3%A9d-d157189845.html</sub>

Comment: Bonjour :) Je suis contente de vous voir, je vais lire vos réponses bientôt ! :) Merci beaucoup !

Comment: On n'y voyait presque jamais DES barques de pêche (P. BENOIT, Axelle, p. 10). [= On y voyait éventuellement des barques, mais non des barques de pêche.] --- Est-ce que ce serait une faute d'écrire _On n'y voyait presque jamais DE barques de pêche_ en tant que négation absolue ? Sans sous-entendu _On y voyait éventuellement des barques, mais non des barques de pêche._ Ou même avec, mais en utilisant toujours "de" ?

Comment: Les comédiennes ne courent pas UN pareil danger  --- Est-ce que vous savez pourquoi 'un' est un numéral ici ? Serait-il possible d'employer 'de" à la place de "un" ?

Comment: Il n’a pas obtenu des résultats vraiment intéressants [Il a bien obtenu des résultats, mais qui ne sont pas intéressants.] --- Cet exemple est semblable à celui avec les barques, non ?

Comment: @Oreste L'introduction « D'une manière générale, _un_ semble se maintenir plus facilement que _du_ ou _des_ », parce que suivit d'un deux-point est applicable à tous les exemples. Donc, on trouvera « un » plus souvent. Cependant, ce qui est correct selon la règle c'est « de » (il n'y a pas de contexte positif, la négation ne porte que sur « danger » et il n'y a pas d'opposition).

Comment: @Oreste Je crois que c'est exact : cas de négation partielle (des résultats mais pas des résultats intéressants).

Answer (score 3):

> Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu une histoire à mes enfants.

Peut signifier que j'ai lu **deux** histoires, ou **trois** ou ....

> Ce soir, je n'ai pas lu d'histoire à mes enfants.

Là, il n'y a aucun doute, je n'ai lu **aucune** histoire à mes enfants.