# Sans espérer un / de miracle

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

Le narrateur pense que Valérian est parti sans le lui dire et il regrette son attitude. Puis, il entend un bruit de pas provenant de la cuisine :

> Sans espérer **un** miracle, je rouvre les yeux et vois Valérian dans
> l’embrasure de la porte.

D'après ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44781/ne-pas-lire-raconter-une-d-histoire), il faut écrire "sans espérer **de** miracle" et pourtant j'ai l'impression que "un" convient mieux ici. Est-ce correct ?

Answer (score 4):

Tout d'abord le TLFi note le syntagme [*espérer*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/esp%C3%A9rer) *un miracle* ; les mots composés sont souvent davantage [figés](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locution_(linguistique)) que des expressions ou locutions, qui le sont néanmoins de manière variable.

> Ensuite on a différents phénomènes dans l'usage touchant les articles,
> quand un nom est [précédé d'une épithète](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11570/26366) ou après un adverbe de degré
> etc. Quand on « transforme une forme affirmative en forme négative »,
> dans certains cas les articles indéfinis associés à des objets directs
> ou un sujet sont **remplacés** par *de*, comme dans *il y a un enfant,
> il n'y a pas d'enfant*. Mais ils se **maintiennent** dans certains
> cas, quand par exemple une partie de la phrase a un sens positif,
> comme dans *on ne fait pas d'omelette sans casser des œufs*. Ou « si
> la négation ne porte pas réellement sur le nom » ou « si le syntagme
> nié s'oppose à un autre syntagme de même fonction ». Par ailleurs,
> quand on a un infinitif introduit avec *sans*, on a dans certains cas
> le même phénomène de remplacement (par *de)* etc. : « Deux domestiques
> entrèrent, sans faire de bruit sur le parquet » (Flaubert).
> Indépendamment, on a aussi ce remplacement par analogie, avec des
> phrases averbales, ou de sens négatif ou « selon un usage récent et
> contestable, par analogie avec *jamais*. *Il y a rarement de loges*
> (Fl. Delay) ». Dans certains cas on a un usage étonnant, comme avec un
> syntagme prépositionnel : *Annie, je ne l'ai jamais vue avec de col*. [qui ne me choque pas du tout.]
>
> L'ensemble du paragraphe paraphrase certains éléments choisis d'une
> présentation exceptionnelle au ***Bon usage***, Grevisse et Goosse, éd.
> Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 584 c) dont la lecture s’avérera incontournable pour vérifier et approfondir ce qui précède.

Dans la question on a la préposition *sans* introduisant le verbe à l'infinitif. On a un phénomène de remplacement. On peut spéculer sur l'adéquation du syntagme avec une exception justifiant qu'on maintienne l'article indéfini original etc.. Enfin on a un syntagme avec l'article *un*.

Généralement *un* me semble plus précis en ce sens que *de* peut évidemment servir pour le pluriel et qu'à l'oral on ne saurait pas. Mais que l'on emploie *un* ou *de*, voire *des*, ne me choque pas du tout, je ne sais même pas si je le remarquerais si ça colle au style du discours etc. La modification du syntagme pour le pluriel avec *des* (*miracles*) me semble moins formelle, mais il y a bien des nuances selon le registre dans mon univers linguistique.

Comment cohabitent le fait que le syntagme soit relativement figé et les nuances de l'usage de l'article indéfini ou partitif est loin d'impliquer que quoi que ce soit soit incorrect à mon avis. En plus il y a d'autres phénomènes qui peuvent être des facteurs, comme la préférence personnelle, la clarté, l'euphonie etc. de sorte que l'[analyse pourrait être différente](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44795/26366) dans la question liée ou selon les mots que l'on trouve dans la phrase et son sens.

Comment: Merci, je pense que _sans espérer **des** miracles_ relève du style familier et s'utilise surtout à l'oral.

Comment: Merci également pour ces précisions, j'ai appris des choses en cours de route !
Ma réponse paraît très pale en comparaison...

Comment: Vous êtes les bienvenus. @GaëtanBoyals Plusieurs types de réponses sont utiles, dont celles qui traitent du réflexe du locuteur, de son expérience etc. En fait je n'en savais pas plus sur le sujet avant d'avoir lu au LBU. Dans la vie de tous les jours, je ne me pose jamais de question concernant la différence de fonction entre l'article défini et indéfini, ni ce qui explique pourquoi je mets _de_ plutôt que _un_ à tel endroit etc. Il s'agit d'usages, et leur présentation implique un choix, que fait Maurice et cie au LBU, par exemple. Le fait de sortir de l'usage n'implique pas l'erreur.

Comment: La réponse illustre des nuances et un cadre. L'article sert une fonction mais parfois il change ou s'estompe selon des contextes d'emploi, selon certaines des fins de la communication ou du sens. Comme l'a dit Oreste par exemple on peut penser que avec le pluriel ça «  relève du style familier et s'utilise surtout à l'oral ». J'aime savoir qu'on dispose de ces nuances.

Comment: *Sans espérer **des** miracles* est pleinement justifié si un seul miracle ne suffit pas à satisfaire l'espoir exprimé, ce qui banalise un peu le miracle...

Comment: @jlliagre Ouais ma réponse est très descriptive et détachée de l'application à l'exemple et à la sémantique dont tu traites dans tes commentaires. Le sens peut certainement justifier le choix et être déterminant.

Answer (score 2):

Dans ce contexte, les deux sont corrects et interchangeables.

En tant que français, je serais tenté d'écrire "**de**" plutôt que "**un**", cela semble et sonne plus correct grammaticalement.

Le [fil mentionné](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44781/ne-pas-lire-raconter-une-d-histoire) est plus ambigu puisque "raconter des histoires" a une double signification et peut aussi signifier "mentir", dépendamment du contexte.

Comment: Merci, je pensais qu'il était préférable d'employer "un" comme dans _Je ne peux réprimer **un** geste d’agacement._  "De" serait curieux ici, non ?

Comment: En effet, "de" ne peut pas être utilisé dans cette phrase. C'est pour ça que j'ai précisé "Dans ce contexte" dans ma réponse ;)

Comment: Merci. Je me demande alors comment je pourrais savoir quand il est incorrect d'employer "de" comme dans _Je ne peux réprimer **un** geste d'impatience._ Poser des questions jusqu'à ce que je ne m'habitue ? Parce que pour moi, _sans espérer **un** miracle_ est plus beau que _sans espérer **de** miracle_ et _Je ne peux réprimer **de** geste_ est moins beau mais toutefois correct...

Comment: Malheureusement, je ne suis pas un expert de la langue française, malgré le fait d'être natif, donc je ne sais pas s'il existe une règle indiscutable là-dessus. (il semblerait que oui, via la réponse de @Zéhontée Bonteuse)
À noter également que les langues évoluent constamment et que le temps a peut-être fait que j'ai plus l'habitude d'entendre "*de* miracle".
Concernant la partie correcte/incorrecte, sauf expert, personne n'aurait remarqué l'utilisation de *un*/*de* dans ce contexte, et les deux formulations sont comprises par tout le monde. ;)

Comment: Merci beaucoup, pour ma part, je pense que, justement, il n'y a pas de règle et qu'il faut s'habituer. Je veux dire qu'il existe une règle de base, sans rien de plus.

Comment: Bonjour Oreste. Il y a quand même quelque chose qui peut aider à choisir la meilleure forme. On ne peut qu'écrire *Je ne peux réprimer **un** geste d'impatience* parce que justement il s'agit d'**un** geste d'impatience. *Un* est ici un adjectif numéral cardinal, pas un article indéfini. On aurait pu éventuellement écrire: *Je ne peux réprimer deux gestes d'impatience* alors que dans le cas du miracle, il s'agit bien d'un miracle hypothétique, indéfini.

Answer (score 0):

Cette question est une suite logique à une question posée par le même demandant et l'on devrait d'abord consulter cette  [question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44781/17649); il est nécessaire d'avoir une bonne compréhension des bases, ce qui peut être obtenu au moyen  des références et du guide à leur compréhension qui sont fournis dans cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/45464/17649). La réponse se trouve dans la même section du LBU qui a été utilisée pour la question à laquelle il est fait référence ci-dessus, c'est à dire «  § 584 c)   de  LBU 14ième édition (**Lorsqu'on transforme une forme affirmative en forme négative.**); c'est en fait le troisième des quatre derniers paragraphes de la section (intitulé « *Avec **sans*** »).

> — L'usage décrit dans le 1° [c'est à dire « remplace[ment] par *de* [des] articles indéfinis ou partitifs accompagnant un objet direct ou un sujet logique (ou réel) », voir la réf.] s'applique aussi à l'infinitif introduit par *sans* et à la proposition introduite par *sans que* :
> ♦ Deux domestiques entrèrent, sans faire DE bruit sur le parquet (FLAUB.,
> Educ., II, 3).
> ♦  C'est à elle qu'immédiatement cette figure m'a fait penser, sans
> qu'il y eût [...] DE ressemblance vraiment frappante (BuTOR, Emploi du temps,
> p. 234).
> Mais il faut la forme pleine quand le verbe principal est négatif:
> ♦ Il ne parle pas sans faire DES fautes [= Il fait des fautes] s'oppose à *II parle sans
> faire DE fautes* [= Il ne fait pas de fautes]
> *De* s'introduit nécessairement avant le nom régime de *sans* quand il y a un adverbe après la préposition.
> L'adverbe fait partie des adverbes auxiliaires de négation (cf. § 1016) :
> ♦ Sans jamais DE curiosité menue et puérile (S.-BEUVE, P.-Royal, III, 15).
> ♦ Sans guère DE chance (H. DE RÉGNIER, Vacances d'un jeune homme sage, p. 231).
> ♦ Sans plus DE baigneurs ni DE touristes, la petite ville reprenait un aspect authentique (GlDE, Feuillets d'automne, p. 50).
> Autres adverbes :
> ♦ Sans même D'inclination (HERRIOT, Mme Récamier et ses amis, p. 218).
> ♦ Sans presque D'efforts (BOURGET, Drames de famille, p. 23).
> ♦ Sans presque D'accent (MAURIAC, Pharisienne, p. 232)

Ceci se comprend sur la base du fait que « sans » est équivalent à une négation absolue.

- Sans réciter de prières vous n'êtes pas un vrai croyant.
- Si vous ne récitez pas de prières vous n'êtes pas un vrai croyant.

Dans la phrase en question « de » est nécessaire sur la base du contexte le plus simple qui soit imaginable, c'est à dire qu'il n'y a aucune référence à un espoir quelconque dans le contexte, ni avant ni après.

- Sans espérer de miracle, je rouvre les yeux et vois Valérian dans l’embrasure de la porte.

Si cela n'est pas vrai, alors « un » devient légitime, selon les mêmes justifications que pour les phrases négatives (1/ sens positif, 2/   négation ne porte pas sur nom, 3/  syntagme  opposé à un autre syntagme de même fonction) (user LPH) et selon que le verbe principal est négatif (LBU, ci-dessus).

- (user LPH) On n'atteint pas cette plage sans passer  un fonds dangereux. (*verbe négatif*)
- (use LPH) On ne fait d'omelette sans casser des œufs. (*verbe négatif dans principale; cela est assez bien vérifié par l'usage établi, mais pas parfaitement; comme le montre cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=omelette+sans+casser+d%27%C5%93ufs%2Comelette+sans+casser+des+%C5%93ufs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Comelette%20sans%20casser%20d%27%20%C5%93ufs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Comelette%20sans%20casser%20des%20%C5%93ufs%3B%2Cc0) le principe n'est pas parfaitement perçu par les utilisateurs du français.*)
- (user LPH) On voit cela sans effectuer des grossissements extrêmes. (*négation porte sur adj.*)
- (user LPH)  Il a  passé sa journée de pêche sans prendre des poissons, que des anguilles qu'il ne voulait pas. (*opposition*)

*Contextes possibles justifiant "un"*

- Je croyais sentir que je trompais, qu'il était toujours là…sans espérer un miracle, je rouvre les yeux et vois Valérian dans l’embrasure de la porte. (*opposition*)
- Sans espérer un miracle, mais avec une faible lueur d'espoir, je rouvre les yeux et vois Valérian dans l’embrasure de la porte. (*opposition*)