# Comment cohabitent le fait qu'un syntagme soit relativement figé et l'usage d'un de ses composants dans la phrase quand il y a antagonisme ?

Tags: usage, locutions, linguistique, phrase

Comment cohabitent le fait qu'un syntagme soit relativement figé et les nuances de l'usage de l'article indéfini ou partitif, [par exemple](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/44793/26366), que contient aussi ce syntagme, quand il y a « antagonisme », comme quand un syntagme s'emploie avec tel article et que le contexte d'emploi en impliquerait l'emploi d'un autre ? Qu'est-ce qui « pèse » le plus dans la langue ?

Comment: SOS reçu, la discussion a été [transférée dans un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122404/discussion-on-question-by-amande-adorable-comment-cohabitent-le-fait-quun-synta).

Comment: Nous aimerions vous aider, mais nous devons d'abord comprendre votre problème. En l'état, votre question est inintelligible.

Comment: @Vincent La question est un prolongement et une abstraction d'une autre question et d'une de mes réponses à cette question, qui paraphrase longuement un extrait du LBU. La question portait sur _sans espérer de miracle_  par opposition à _sans espérer un miracle_. Voir : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/44805/26366 En résumé c'est l'impact du contexte sur l'usage de l'article dans un syntagme.