# Sans émettre de / un commentaire

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Mes amis et moi les fixons durant de longues secondes sans bouger,
> sans émettre **de** commentaire.
>
> Mes amis et moi les fixons durant de longues secondes sans bouger,
> sans émettre **un** commentaire.

Selon ce [fil](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44793/sans-esp%C3%A9rer-un-de-miracle), les deux options sont possibles, mais la première est-elle plus courante ?

Comment: Les deux ne veulent pas dire la même chose...

Answer (score 4):

Les deux sont possibles, mais le sens n'est pas tout à fait le même. « Sans émettre de commentaire » dit exactement ce qu'elle a l'air de dire : nous ne faisons pas de commentaire. « Sans émettre un commentaire » est plus fort : elle insiste sur le fait que nous aurions pu émettre un commentaire, et même plusieurs commentaires, mais nous ne le faisons pas.

En terme de force, « sans émettre de commentaire » est neutre. « Sans émettre un commentaire » est plus fort. « Sans émettre le moindre commentaire » serait encore un peu plus fort.

An English analogy would be “without making any comment” vs “without making a single comment”.