# Négation verbes modaux (auxiliaires) + articles partitifs ou "de"

Tags: négation, partitif

Are both sentences correct? I think both are possible:

1. Je ne veux pas boire d'eau.
2. Je ne veux pas boire de l'eau.

The difference is:

1. I don't want to drink water at all.
2. I don't want to drink water, but I'd like to drink something else.

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ne pas lire (raconter) une / d' histoire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44781/ne-pas-lire-raconter-une-d-histoire)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both sentences are fine and they mean what you state.

The second sentence is rarer as such because it has kind of an implicit hidden trailer:

> *Je ne veux pas boire de l'eau (**mais** [**qque chose d'autre**]*).

The first sentence also somewhat imply that you want to drink something else. Otherwise that would have been either ***je ne veux pas boire***, ***je ne veux rien boire*** or just ***je n'ai pas soif***.

Réference:

> Les articles indéfinis ou partitifs se maintiennent
> [...]
> — Si le syntagme nié s'oppose à un autre syntagme de même fonction : *Elle n'a pas demandé **Du** vin, mais de la bière.*
> — L'opposition est implicite : *Nous ne disons pas **DU** mal de lui !* (IONESCO, Amédée,
> p. 256.)
> Grevisse, Le bon usage 14<sup>e</sup> édition, §584, p 750.

Comment: Oui, mais la deuxième aussi, pourrait vouloir dire qu'on ne veut pas d'eau en particulier... Je ne sens pas si la différence est vraiment vraie, très ténue, dans l'oreille du beholder, ou bien en voie de disparition...

Comment: @Frank Soit je ne comprends pas ton commentaire, soit tu ne comprends pas ma réponse. Je dis bien que les deux veulent dire la même chose, la première implicitement, la deuxième explicitement.

Comment: Oui, les deux veulent dirent la même chose, à tel point pour moi que le commentaire _I would add that the first one also somewhat imply that you want to drink something else._ me semble discutable :-) Je ne crois pas qu'on puisse casser la symétrie de ces deux phrases, donc _the first one_ n'a rien de spécial à mes yeux.

Comment: @Frank La deuxième phrase dit clairement qu'on veut boire autre chose. La première le sous-entend seulement et n'exclut pas totalement qu'on ne veut rien boire du tout. Les deux phrases ne sont pas équivalentes pour moi.

Comment: Pas évident pour moi: "_Je ne veux pas boire d'eau_", réponse possible: "_OK, tu veux du vin plutôt?_". "_Je ne veux pas boire de l'eau_", réponse possible: "_tu veux autre chose?_". S'il y a une différence, elle est trop subtile pour moi. Je ne pense pas que je ferais vraiment attention à une différence dans une conversation courantes, et je ne modifierais pas mon comportment/ma réponse en conséquence. Mais de toute façon, c'est un peu "guindé" pour une vraie conversation familière, à mon avis.

Comment: @Frank "Je ne veux pas boire d'eau", réponse possible: "Ah bon, tu n'as pas soif ?" mais "Je ne veux pas boire de l'eau", réponse possible "Tu veux boire quoi alors ?"

Comment: Peut-être... peut-être, mais c'est pas une règle. Tu comprends et tu réponds comme tu veux (et ça, c'est une règle ;-)